# Hermiticity/self-adjointness of the Laplacian operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, differential-operators

I'm trying to understand the concept of hermicity/self-adjointness but even after reading through some threads here, I just don't get it (first problem being that I don't understand the difference between the two, if there is any). But anyway, let's look e. g. at the one-dimensional eigenvalue problem of the Laplace operator $$\Delta f(x)=\frac{d^2}{dx^2} f(x)=cf(x)$$ where $c$ is a constant and the domain $\Omega$ for $x$ is e. g. $[x_0;x_1]$. From what I've read, the Laplace operator is self-adjoint/hermitian for boundary constraints $f(x_0)=f(x_1)=0$ (though I don't know why that is). Could someone expain why? (And maybe also showcase a set of BCs for which the Laplacian operator is not self-adjoint/hermitian?)

Comment: You can just check the definition of hermitian operator. The trick is integration by parts. In particular, you will see why the boundary conditions are convenient.

Comment: Well yes, Wikipedia says: "A bounded operator $A : H → H$ is called Hermitian or self-adjoint if $A = A^*$ which is equivalent to $⟨Ax,y⟩ = ⟨x ,Ay⟩\space for \space all \space x, y ∈ H$." Unfortunately, that doesn't really help me a lot. Can someone elaborate what this definition means applied to the Laplacian operator?

Comment: The way I understand, the (however defined) inner product of the operator $A$ applied to one vector $x$ with a second vector $y$ must be the same as the inner product of vector $x$ with the operator $A$ applied to vector $y$. But how do I check that in practice? And how does it relate to integration by parts?

Comment: @chiken_game: It is not trivial ... there is a difference between symmetric/hermitian and self-adjoint. Symmetry is straightforward, however self-adjoint is rather technical. I have posted answer.

Answer (score 5):

The Laplacian is only partially defined on $L^2$ and it is unbounded. Usually, the Laplacian is defined on the dense subspace of compactly supported smooth functions and is extended to a self-adjoint closure (still partially defined only).

For a partially defined operator $A: D(A)\subseteq L^2 \to L^2$, it is self-adjoint by definition if and only if $D(A) = D(A^*)$ and for every $f,g\in D(A)$ it follows $$\int f Ag = \int Af g. $$

I will explain the symmetry for functions in one variable for sake of simplicity. Consider $\Delta: C_c^\infty(a, b) \subseteq L^2(a, b) \to L^2(a, b)$ defined by $\Delta f = f''$ and $f,g\in C_c^\infty(a, b)$. By integration by parts, it follows
$$ \langle f, \Delta g \rangle = \int_a^b f g'' = \underbrace{[f g']_a^b}_{=0} - \int_a^b f' g' = -\underbrace{[f' g]_a^b}_{=0} + \int_a^b f'' g = \langle \Delta f, g \rangle. $$
That is, $\Delta$ is symmetric, and thus, we have $D(\Delta) \subseteq D(\Delta^*)$. But, for example $D(\Delta^*)$ also contains $C^2(a,b)$ and is larger than $D(\Delta)$. Thus, $\Delta$ is not self-adjoint. However, as $-\Delta$ is a non-negative (or positive semidefinite), there are many ways to extend $-\Delta$ to a self-adjoint operator.

Comment: Ok. To clarify, I get that (1) $D$ stands for domain. (2) You define the inner product $⟨.,.⟩$ to be the product integral. Is that the only possible definition? (3) Symmetry (which equals hermicity) means $⟨f,Δg⟩=⟨Δf,g⟩$. (4) For bounded operators, symmetry equals self-adjointness, but for unbounded operators (like $Δ$), symmetry is necessary, but not sufficient for self-adjointness. Symmetry depends on the BCs, right? (5) Is symmetry without self-adjointness (in practice) sufficient to produce an orthonormal eigenvector basis? Wikipedia says not necessarily:

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-adjoint_operator

Comment: @chicken_game (2) the inner product on $L^2$ is defined by the integral. This is the usual Hilbert space, if it isn't mentioned. But there are obviously other inner products and thus other Hilbert spaces. (4) yes, symmetry only holds on a sub space of $L^2$. (5) well, Wikipedia already has given your a answer :)

Comment: Ok. So if I we want to guarantee an orthonormal basis, we need to modify $\Delta$ to be self-adjoint? What would be a possible way to do that (if there is one)?

Comment: @chicken_game: In full generality, please check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensions_of_symmetric_operators. If you can stay in 1-d, you can use periodic boundary conditions as in disintegrating-by-parts's answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try to link the answers. Concerning the notation: What does $C^∞_c$ stand for? And how do you ensure that $[fg']^b_a=[f'g]^b_a=0$? (since I see no BCs)

Comment: @chicken_game: $C_c^\infty$ means compactly supported smooth functions. As I use an open domain $(a, b)$, this implies that the function and all its derivatives vanish at the boundary. In fact, in 1-d you can also take $D(\Delta)$ as space of $C^1$ functions  which vanish at the boundary and whose derivative is absolutely continuous. This should make $\Delta$ self-adjoint. This is like disintegrating-by-parts's answer, just with your boundary condition.

Comment: So if the function has roots on $(a,b)$ the support is still considered to be compact? Regarding the domain of $\Delta^*$, how do we know it is not the same as that of $\Delta?$ Or do we have to assume it has the "largest possible" domain? If so, does that imply we can make $\Delta$ self-adjoint by just giving it the largest possible domain (since that means $D(\Delta^*)=D(\Delta)$)?

Comment: @chicken_game: (1) A compactly supported function may have roots inside its support. In fact, the zero function is compactly supported. A function that is not compactly supported is for example $x\mapsto x$ on any open set. (2) For my definition of $\Delta$, we have $D(\Delta) \subsetneq C^2(a, b) \subseteq D(\Delta^*)$. (3) You need to increase $D(\Delta)$ until it equals $D(\Delta^*)$.

Comment: I think number (2) is what it comes down to: If that is, as you say, "your definition of $\Delta$", what would prevent someone from just defining $D(\Delta)=D(\Delta^*)$ per default and thus always ensuring self-adjointness?

Comment: @chicken_game if you know the suitable domain, you can obviously start with that.

Comment: But how do I know the suitable domain? I mean, one can't just go "I know it because I defined it so", right? That would be an end in itself.

Answer (score 2):

If $f,g$ are twice absolutely continuous on $[x_0,x_1]$ with $f,g,f'',g''\in L^2[x_0,x_1]$, then
$$
       \langle f'',g\rangle-\langle f,g''\rangle=\int_{x_0}^{x_1}f''\overline{g}-f\overline{g''}dx \\
   = \int_{x_0}^{x_1}\frac{d}{dx}(f'\overline{g}-f\overline{g'})dx \\
   = \left.\det\left(\begin{array}{cc}\overline{g(x)} & f(x) \\ \overline{g'(x)} & f'(x)\end{array}\right)\right|_{x_0}^{x_1}.
$$
$\Delta$ is symmetric if the determinants given above at $x_1,x_2$ are $0$ for all $f,g$ in the domain. This typically involves imposing endpoint conditions on $f,g$ such as
$$
                    \cos\alpha f(x_0)+\sin\alpha f'(x_0) = 0, \\
                    \cos\beta f(x_1)+\sin\beta f'(x_1) = 0.
$$
For $\alpha = 0 = \beta$, this amounts to imposing $f(x_0)=f(x_1)=0$. If $f,g$ satisfy these conditions, then $\langle f'',g\rangle = \langle f,g''\rangle$ for all $f,g$ satisfying $0$ endpoint conditions at $x=x_0,x_1$. But, as you can see, many other conditions give rise to a symmetric operator $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$.

Symmetry does not imply self-adjointness of $Lf=f''$. However, symmetry is necessary. It turns out that $L_{\alpha,\beta}$ given by $Lf=f''$ with $f$ being twice absolutely continuous with $f''\in L^2$ is self-adjoint. There are periodic conditions that can imposed that will also result in self-adjoint operators. Examples of non-selfadjoint versions of $L$ include conditions
$$
               f(x_0)=f'(x_0)=f(x_1)=f'(x_1)=0.
$$
Then $L^*$ is the unrestricted operator $L$ (i.e., one with no endpoint conditions.) In particular $\langle Lf,g\rangle = \langle f,L^*g\rangle$ for all $f$ satisfying $f(x_0)=f'(x_0)=f(x_1)=f'(x_1)=0$ and $g$ unrestricted.

If $A : \mathcal{D}(A)\rightarrow\mathcal{H}$ is a linear operator on a dense subspace of a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, then one way to define the adjoint $A^*$ is that the domain $\mathcal{D}(A^*)$ consists of all $y\in\mathcal{H}$ such that
$$
      |\langle Ax,y\rangle | \le M \|x\|,\;\;\; x\in\mathcal{H}.
$$
Then, $x\mapsto \langle Ax,y\rangle$ extends by continuity to a continuous linear function on $\mathcal{H}$ and, so, there exists a unique $z\in\mathcal{H}$ such that $\langle Ax,y\rangle = \langle x,z\rangle$ for all $x\in\mathcal{H}$. Define the adjoint operator $A^*$ on $y$ by $A^*y=z$. Then,
$$
              \langle Ax,y\rangle = \langle x,A^*y\rangle,\;\; x\in\mathcal{D}(A),\;y\in\mathcal{D}(A^*).
$$
$0$ is always in the domain of the adjoint with $A^*0=0$. In order to prove more about the domain of $A^*$, you can write the adjoint relation as an inner product condition in $\mathcal{H}\times\mathcal{H}$:
$$
         \left\langle \left[\begin{array}{c}Ax \\ x\end{array}\right],\left[\begin{array}{c}y\\-A^*y\end{array}\right]\right\rangle = 0
$$
Using this observation, it can be shown that, if $A$ is densely defined and closed (which means its graph is closed), then $A^*$ is closed and densely-defined. This is done by looking at orthogonal complements in $\mathcal{H}\times\mathcal{H}$.

Comment: Oh, somehow I missed your answer. Must have been a bug or I accidentally scrolled over it, sorry.

Comment: I'll try to bring your answers together. Let me ask a few things: (1) Where does your first equation $⟨f′′,g⟩−⟨f,g′′⟩=...$ come from? (2) Crossbars stand for the complex conjugate, right? (3) A zero determinant ensures symmetry. Adding the stated Robin BCs (which include Neumann/Dirichlet BCs) and the twice continuity of $f$ ensures self-adjointness (since they ensure the operator is bounded, c. f. my comments below). I presume $L_{\alpha,\beta}$ refers to these BCs. (4) Wouldn't the second set of BCs be an overconstraint? (4 BCs for a 2nd order differential equation?)

Comment: For clarification, by second set I mean $f(x_0)=f'(x_0)=f(x_1)=f'(x_1)=0$

Comment: @chicken_game : I had a little more time, so I left you more in the outline of the development of the Hilbert space adjoint.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts Would you mind extending your explanation on why $L:C^2\cap\{f''\in L^2\}\mapsto \frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ turns out to be self-adjoint? (Also, just to be sure: do you consider this operator in the Hilbert space $L^2$ or another space?)

Comment: @Rem : That's not what I mean. The natural self-adjoint domain for $L=\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ consists of functions $f$ that are equal a.e. to twice absolutely continuous functions with $f,f''\in L^2$.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts OK. Just to be sure, do you mean that $L$ as an operator from the set of $C^2$ functions with $f,f''\in L^2$ to $L^2$ is a self-adjoint operator?

Comment: @Rem : $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ is not self-adjoint on $C^2$ in $L^2$, even with the proper endpoint conditions. It is essentially self-adjoint with the correct endpoint conditions, meaning that the closure of the operator is self-adjoint, but it is not strictly self-adjoint.

Comment: Some remarks: (1) Shouldn't it be $A:D(A)→\mathcal{H}$ rather than $A:D(\mathcal{H})→{H}?$ I mean, the domain of $\mathcal{H}$ is $\mathcal{H}$, right? (2) What does $M$ stand for? (3) I think a word is missing here: "Then, $x↦⟨Ax,y⟩$ extends by continuous ??? to a continuous linear function..."